# Returning a pointer to an member array from const member function

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

Why the following code is giving me an error

Test.cpp:23:10: error: invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive] return array;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ELEMENTS 5
class CBase
{

public:
    CBase()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMENTS; i++)
        {
            array[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    ~CBase()
    {
        // Nothing
    }
    int * GetArray() const
    {
        return array;
    }

private:
    int array[MAX_ELEMENTS];

};

int main ()
{
    CBase b;
    return 1;
}
```

EDIT: I understand that I should return a const int * but then I tried something below which works fine, request to explain the reason for allowing this and not allowing the above.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

class CBase
{
public:
    CBase():ptr(NULL)
    {
    }
    ~CBase()
    {
        delete ptr;
    }
    int * ptr;
public:
    int * GetPtr() const
    {
        return ptr;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    CBase b;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It really does break const-correctness when you let the caller modify a const object's data.

Comment: Try `const int * GetArray() const {...}`

Comment: because your const method should return `int const*` and not `int*`

Comment: but then how const member function returning plain variable as it is (i.e. non array) without any error?

Comment: @user3271978, It works exactly the same way. You don't have to return a `const int * const`, just like you don't have to return a `const double` or something. The return value is copied out.

Comment: Side note: `main` should probably not return 1 unless there's some error.

Comment: @chris thanks this clears the air however does the same logic apply to pointers as well ? please check my edited question

Comment: The same rule applies, the return value is *copied*. So this time you copy the pointer. However, the pointer does not point to a member of your class but some arbitrary memory location. so changing the *copy* of ptr does not change b.ptr! What would not work, however, would be returning a pointer to ptr. So returning &ptr what would be an int **. See my answer below for the details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine code like this:

```
const CBase b;
int *array = b.GetArray();
array[0] = 5; // ooops! b changed but we declared it const!?
```

So as already mentioned in the comments, it does break const-correctness of your code. What you need to do is either declare GetArray() non-const, or make it return a pointer to a const int.

```
const int * GetArray() const 
{
    return array;
}
```

Now, code like this would not compile:

```
const CBase b;
const int *array = b.GetArray();
array[0] = 5;
```

**EDIT**
To answer your other question from the comments above: When you call a method that returns a value and you assign this return value to some variable, than the return value is *copied* to your variable and afterwards discarded. So when your calling code changes the value of this variable this has no effect on the value or variable that was initially returned. That is why a const member function can return some of the class' data members. However, when you return a *pointer* to a data member, than the calling code can manipulate the value of this member. Still, the pointer is copied, but even the copy points to the memory location where the class member is stored and thus you could manipulate its value.

Comment: I think your example would be better if `b` was `const`.

Answer (score 2):

Your method should return a `const int*` instead.

```
const int * GetArray() const
{
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple you need to either declare GetArray() non-const, or make it return a pointer to a const int.

```
const int * GetArray() const
{
    return array;
}
```

The reason is that if you return non constant array then as array is returned as pointer so its value can be changed by function which gets its value so constant function indirectly results in changing the value so you need to return constant array.